# Windows 7 freezes at first startup and crashes randomly with graphical glitches - Why?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

My parent's Windows 7 Pro machine freezes (requiring reboot) once (sometimes twice) a day before booting and functioning normally. The freezes occurs when already in desktop and seen to not be related to anything particularly.

Also, sometimes they get this glitch/error:

[image]

The PC is used for common daily tasks (email, facebook, word processor). It is a Core 2 Duo E7500, G31 chipset, 4GB RAM. No discrete graphics.

So what's are the issues I should be looking for? Defective onboard graphics? Faulty power supply? Malware? Is it possible for a onboard graphics card become defective?

Answer (score 0):

Defective RAM or Onboard Graphics are the likely options here. As the machine doesn't have a dedicated graphics card, it will be sharing the onboard RAM, so this is quite possibly the cause.

**Testing RAM**

I'd recommend running [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) or an equivalent RAM test. If you get an error, you can try re-seating the RAM and trying again, or test each stick individually. One or both may need to be replaced. As they would usually be supplied in pairs it's possible the other *may* fail at a similar time, although this of course isn't a guarantee, and replacing both is usually the best option.

**Testing Graphics**

If the memory tests pass, then it's likely the graphics card at fault. You can run tests on this with software such as [furmark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/), and if it is faulty you'll likely get severe corruption or a blue screen. If this is your problem, you ***could*** add a cheap dedicated graphics card to use instead, **however**, as this component is on the motherboard it could be a sign of further issues to come. It may buy you some more time, another component may fail soon after, or it might last a lifetime, it's hard to tell.

Either way, there is very likely a hardware fault somewhere. You can also update the graphics driver if applicable, but it's not the most likely option.

Comment: Thanks Jonno, I will perform these tests and report back. Curiously, you didn't mentioned power supply issues. Once, with a different computer, I got a graphics card burnt because of a faulty PSU.

Comment: @Hydren With onboard graphics it's fairly unlikely (I've not seen a case of it at least), whereas with dedicated graphics cards that get power directly from the PSU that could be a symptom. For the onboard graphics to be failing due to a bad PSU I'd expect you to be getting more random results than graphics failures

Comment: I've tested with memtest86+ and it passed. However, I couldn't bechmark it with furmark as it requires a OpenGL 2.0 or higher capable graphics and my onboard graphics is a Intel G31/G33, which support up to OpenGL 1.4.